Сreate a copy-protected channel using telethon
How to create a copy-protected channel using telethon? I didn’t find anything in the official documentation, and I doubt whether this is possible. The point is that a channel is created in which material that cannot be copied is published.
I try create private group, and i made it. But i don'n geting link to invite. About copy protect, i dont know how make it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

After creating a channel with CreateChannel you can use ToggleNoForwards to enable restricted content.
You can either extract the created channel from the updates returned by the first method, or simply fetch it via client.get_dialogs. Copying the auto-generated example for Telethon v1:
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.messages.ToggleNoForwardsRequest(
        peer='username',
        enabled=False
    ))
    print(result.stringify())

enabled=False will disable content protection, while enable=True will enable it.
